# Select Children when selecting Parent checkbox

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using a Grid where the first column is checkbox. Every row is a folder which can have many other elements to be selected. There could be another folder inside a folder.

Now, when I have to select a element I have to select it one by one. I am not able to understand that how could I make it possible that if I check a folder checkbox, It checks the all selectable elements inside this folder.

Please let me know if more info required.

```
    RemoteSortTreeLoader<BasicModel> loader = 
        new BaseRemoteSortTreeLoader<BasicModel>(proxy, reader) {                   
            public boolean hasChildren(BasicModel parent) {                 
                //code;
            }
        };
    TreeStore store = new TreeStore(loader);        
    List<ColumnConfig> columnList = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();      
    CheckBoxSelectionModel checkBoxSelectionModel = 
        new CheckBoxSelectionModel();
    columnList.add(checkBoxSelectionModel.getColumn());
    ColumnModel columns = new ColumnModel(columnList);
    EditorTreeGrid grid = new EditorTreeGrid<BasicModel>(store,columns);
    grid.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SIMPLE);
    grid.getSelectionModel().addListener(Events.BeforeSelect, 
        new Listener<SelectionEvent<BasicModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(SelectionEvent<BasicModel> event) {                 
                if (event.getModel() instanceof SDPTimelineCatalogModel) {
                    event.setCancelled(false);
                    }
            } // handleEvent        
        }
    );

    grid.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedListener(
        new SelectionChangedListener<BasicModel>() {

            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<BasicModel> event) {
                logger.info(" Inside addSelectionChangedListener ");
                if (event.getSelection().size() == 0) {
                    disableNext();
                } else {
                    enableNext();                       
                }

            } // selectionChanged

            }
    );
```

thanks

Comment: Are you using a TreeGrid

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am using TreeGrid.

Comment: If you are using a TreeGrid, you will have a TreeStore. If you are selecting a folder, the responding DTO in your TreeStore will have a reference to the children.

Comment: Ôn which Object and on which event I should try to select the children? I have tried to do it on CheckBoxSelectionModel Events (SelectionEvent and SelectionChangedEvent) but it is not helpful. I don't find any helpful event on Model object as well. Please advise.

Comment: event.getSelectedItem() should help.